# iOS - How can I randomly position pizza ingredient images over and within the bounds of a pizza crust image?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am trying to build a pizza viewer in an iOS app that has a pizza crust as a base image, and as the user makes selections for adding ingredients, I want to be able to add the ingredient images randomly to cover the pizza.

Some points to call out:

- The pizza is a circle
- The scatter zone should be a subset of the pizza crust (I don't want images showing up on the crust area)
- I'd like to be able to specify halves (right half only, left half only, or whole pizza)
- It would be ideal to minimize overlap of ingredients as much as possible.
- Ingredient images are of the chopped ingredient as it will lay on the pizza. To avoid having them all look the same, switching up the orientation and position would be ideal to give a random look and feel.

I haven't done anything like this before so I am just trying to get pointed in the right direction. How can I approach solving a problem like this? I'm not necessarily looking for code snippets as much as help with a theoretical approach to this problem.

Comment: I suggest you to read some articles on CoreGraphics and start coding... the scope of this question is very large

Comment: have you tried to use a randome number generator for both the x and the y axes for the positioning and have the max and min of both within the area of the crust.

Answer (score 2):

Learn to live with white stuff on your pizza.
Seriously though you really should use .png images. If there are no png images available than us gimp on a pc to crop it out and put it on a rgba #000000ff background.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment. I'm planning on using PNG images, the question was more around strategies for handling the placement of the images.

Answer (score 1):

Hey this might not be what you want, but wouldn't be a simpler approach to create the toppings png image (transparent background) for each ingredient (since you will have to anyways) having 2 of each. One with the specific ingredient on the full pizza and the other one in half? And then depending on which side the user chooses, just flip the image using the `imageOrientation` method. I think this way you could have more control on how to "spread out" the ingredients.

Maybe this is not the answer that you are looking for but it's an option. Good luck! :)

Comment: I think this is a good suggestion. Depending on how complicated doing it the "right" way turns out to be, this approach might make the most sense. Thanks for sharing!